# MVC5 Ajax.BeginForm Load Laout page again

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I,m using `Ajax.BeginForm` from smooth result without refreshing but view page layout page load again under lauout page,

**Js referense:**

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.11.1-min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js"></script>
```

**My View(razor):**

```
<div id="divSbStmt">
    @using (Ajax.BeginForm("DetailedStatement", "Account", new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST", UpdateTargetId = "divSbStmt" }, new { @sid = sid, @tid = tid }))
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        <input type="hidden" value="detailstmt" id="hfDownloadView">
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.SessionID)
    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-sm-3" for="ddlAccountNo">Select Account</label>
            <div class="col-sm-3">
                @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.AccountNo, new SelectList(ViewBag.Acclst, "Value", "Text"), new { @class = "form-control", @id = "ddlAccountNo" })
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="divTransDate" class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-sm-3">Transaction Date</label>
            <div class="col-sm-3 padbot3px">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.FromDate, new { @class = "form-control input-number", @id = "txtFromDate", @placeholder = "From Date (DDMMYYYY)", @maxlength = "8" })
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-3 padbot3px">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.ToDate, new { @class = "form-control input-number", @id = "txtToDate", @placeholder = "To Date (DDMMYYYY)", @maxlength = "8" })
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-3">
                <button id="btnAdvSearch" type="button" class="btn btn-adv-search" onclick="showAdvancedSearch()"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span> Advanced Search</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="divAdvancedSearch" class="advance-search-panel">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-sm-3">Amount From</label>
                <div class="col-sm-3 padbot3px">
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.FromAmount, "", new { @class = "form-control input-decimal", @id = "txtFromAmt", @maxlength = "15" })
                </div>
                <label class="col-sm-1">To</label>
                <div class="col-sm-3">
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.ToAmount, new { @class = "form-control input-decimal", @id = "txtToAmt", @maxlength = "15" })
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-sm-3">Cheque No From</label>
                <div class="col-sm-3 padbot3px">
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.FromInstrNo, "", new { @class = "form-control input-number", @id = "txtFromCno", @maxlength = "6" })
                </div>
                <label class="col-sm-1">To</label>
                <div class="col-sm-3">
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.ToInstrNo, "", new { @class = "form-control input-number", @id = "txtToCno", @maxlength = "6" })
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-sm-3">Particulars</label>
                <div class="col-sm-3 padbot3px">
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Particulars, "", new { @class = "form-control", @id = "txtParticulars", @maxlength = "50" })
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-sm-3">Transaction Type</label>
                <div class="col-sm-3">
                    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.TransType, new SelectList((IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.Transaction, "Value", "Text"), "Select", new { @class = "form-control", @id = "ddlTransType" })
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-sm-offset-3 col-sm-3">
                <button id="btnGetStatement" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-file"></span> Show Statement</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="divDtlStatement">
            @if (Model.DtlStmtBal != null)
            {
            <table class="table mytable">
                <tbody>
                    @foreach (var StmtBal in Model.DtlStmtBal)
                        {
                        <tr>
                            <td width="20%">@StmtBal.Key</td>
                            <td width="80%">@StmtBal.Value</td>
                        </tr>
                        }
                </tbody>
            </table>
            <div class="col-sm-12" id="dtlStatementContent">
                <div id="divDtlTable" class="form-group">
                    <table id="tblDtlStmDtl" width="100%" class="table nowrap dt-responsive">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                @foreach (var stmHead in Model.DtlStmtHead)
                                    {
                                    <th>@stmHead</th>
                                    }
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        @for (int i = 0; i < Model.DtlStmtData.Count; i++)
                            {
                                List<string> listData = Model.DtlStmtData[i];
                                if (i == 0)
                                {
                            <input type="hidden" value="@listData[i]" id="hfGridData" />
                                }
                            <tr>
                                @for (int j = 0; j < listData.Count; j++)
                                    {
                                    <td align=@Model.DtlAlignment[j]>@listData[j]</td>
                                    }
                            </tr>
                            }
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
            }
        </div>
    </div>
    }
    @using (Html.BeginForm("DownloadDatas", "Download", new { @downloadView = "detailstmt" }, FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal", role = "form" }))
    {
        <div id="divDownload" class="form-group" style="display:none">
            <div class="col-sm-2 padding3px">
                @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.DownLoadType, new SelectList((IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.DropDownListDefault, "Value", "Text"), "Select", new { @class = "form-control", @id = "ddlDownload" })
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-2 padding3px">
                <button id="btnDownload" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-download"></span> Download</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    }
    @if (ViewBag.Message != null && ViewBag.ErrorNo == 11)
    {
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-sm-12">
                <span class="alert alert-danger" style="display:block;width:98%;">@ViewBag.Message</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    }
</div>
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Your question isn't clear. You mean your page reloads when form posts?

Comment: Yes its already added layout page but after posting again its loaded layout page

Comment: Since you have two forms in ur view, on which form post does the page reload?

Comment: after click btnGetStatement button

Answer (score 0):

You problem is you return `view` rather than `PartialView`.

You have to do:

1. Separate your `form`  into a `PartialView`.
2. Call `Html.RenderAction() OR Html.Partial() OR Html.RenderPartial()` for rendering `Partialview`.

3.After Submitting your form Return your `PartialView`.